# MongoDB aggregate: $lookup by _id, then get first element value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

When I do `$lookup`, in my case the `foreignField:"_id"`, I get the found element in an array. Here is one document from the output after `$lookup` has been done to retrieve `fromUser` and `toUser` from the `users` collection:

```
{ 
    _id : { from : 57b8da368e4a6e1f0043cb3d, to : 57c381af7008e51f009d92df }, 
    fromUser : [
        {
            _id : 57b8da368e4a6e1f0043cb3d, 
            userName: "A"
        }
    ], 
    toUser : [
        {
            _id : 57c381af7008e51f009d92df, 
            userName: "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can notice `fromUser` and `toUser` are arrays. How to project `fromUser` and `toUser` so instead of arrays they contain just the user's `userName`, like here:

```
{
    _id : { from : 57b8da368e4a6e1f0043cb3d, to : 57c381af7008e51f009d92df },
    fromUser: "A",
    toUser: "B"
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can achieve that by appending a `$project` stage using the [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#arrayelemat-aggregation) operator to your aggregation pipeline like this

```
// your previous stages incl. lookup
...
$project: {
    fromUser: { $arrayElemAt: ["$fromUser.userName", 0] },
    toUser: { $arrayElemAt: ["$toUser.userName", 0] }
}
...
```

Comment: You taught me 3 things today: formatting, reading docs more carefully, and the answer. Thank you!

Comment: You can use $first: "$fromUser.userName" too.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the first element in array, then you can use **[$first](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)** operator (New in version 4.4) and its simple to use.

```
{
    $set: {
        fromUser: {
            $first: "$fromUser.userName" 
        },
        toUser: {
            $first: "$toUser.userName" 
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to get other than first element in an array, then you can use **$arrayElemAt** operator.